# querying specific data from Spotify API

Tags: request, spotify

The Spotify [web API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/search/) is not well documented, or at least I couldn't find what i was looking for.

I want to get all the artists that start with an **"A"** (for example).

If i do this (node.js):

```
    var options = {
        host: 'ws.spotify.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/search/1/artist.json?q=a',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
```

I get the artists that *have* an **"A"** not the ones that start with **"A"**.
This is just a basic example but i'm guessing i'll run into this problem later on as well.

Can this be done or it depends on their API?
Do regular expressions work for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions don't work with this API. The [advanced search syntax](http://www.spotify.com/se/about/features/advanced-search-syntax/) does, though.

Comment: So... I can't search artist alphabetically by name, right? For what's in these docs the extra parameters are only `artist`,`year`, etc. Would that be the only way of enhancing a query?

Comment: That's correct. The search API isn't designed to be an API for scraping/listing the entire catalog, but rather optimised for how humans would use search to find stuff. The query structure reflects that.